# Ruby Prime Factorization Error

Tags: ruby

I made a prime factorizaton program in ruby. It solves 8-9 digit numbers, but when I add a 10 digit number to the program, and it donesn't solve. For debug I wrote all steps in the loop, and the program solves, but not finish. It will be run forever. Here is the code:

```
require 'prime'
primSzamok = [1767172329]

def prim_dem(n)
  base = n / 2
  pf = Array.new
  i = 2
    while i <= base
      if Prime.prime?(i)
        while n % i == 0
          pf << i
          n /= i
          puts "i: #{i}, base: #{base}, n: #{n}"
        end
      end
      i += 1
    end
  return pf
end

haromCount = 0

primSzamok.each do |number|
  primArr = prim_dem(number)
  primString = "["

  iCount = 0
  primArr.each do |v|
    if iCount == 0
      primString += "#{v}"
    else
      primString += ", #{v}"
    end

    if v == 3
      haromCount += 1
    end

    iCount += 1
  end
  primString += "]"

  puts "Number: #{number} | Primes: #{primString}"
end
```

Comment: Note: since you have already required prime, you just have this available:`p 1767172329.prime_division` , resulting in [[3, 3], [13, 3], [31, 3]].

Comment: As mentioned above, if you go to the bother of including 'prime' then you are recreating the wheel.  Seems to hang for 8 and 9 digit numbers for me too.  Assuming this is an exercise, try starting again and remove the require and see if you can workout a good method for this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to check upto `(n/2)` numbers, check upto `sqrt(n)` because `sqrt(n) * sqrt(n) = n` means at worst case, large prime number will decomposed to two mid size prime numbers else `n` itself is prime, iterating upto `n/2` numbers will take too much time.

change base to `base = sqrt(n)`

```
require 'prime'
primSzamok = [1767172329]

def prim_dem(n)
  base = sqrt(n)
  pf = Array.new
  i = 2
    while i <= base
      if Prime.prime?(i)
        while n % i == 0
          pf << i
          n /= i
          puts "i: #{i}, base: #{base}, n: #{n}"
        end
      end
      i += 1
    end
  return pf
end

haromCount = 0

primSzamok.each do |number|
  primArr = prim_dem(number)
  primString = "["

  iCount = 0
  primArr.each do |v|
    if iCount == 0
      primString += "#{v}"
    else
      primString += ", #{v}"
    end

    if v == 3
      haromCount += 1
    end

    iCount += 1
  end
  primString += "]"

  puts "Number: #{number} | Primes: #{primString}"
end
```